# Will my browser cache favicons from data URL

Tags: html, favicon, data-url

I would like to use the following base64 favicon and maybe some base64 images.

```
<link href="data:image/x-icon;base64,AAABAAEAEBAAAAAAAABoBQAAFgAAACgAAAAQAAAAIAAAAAEACAAAAAAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEAAAAAAA..AMAK3WxwAOWT0AK4RgAKHOvQA4hWUAP4lqAD2MagBQm3kATKSBAECcdP//AAD8/wAA+H8AAPA/AADwPwAA4B8AAMAPAACABwAAAgMAAI8BAADfgAAA/8AAAP/AAAD/4QAA//MAAP//AAA=" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" />
```

Will these get cached by my browser?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No. Data URIs are not separately cached from their containing documents (e.g. CSS or HTML files) so data is downloaded every time the containing documents are redownloaded.

[Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme)

Answer (score 5):

[Caching your site's favicon](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#favicon) is actually *recommended* as a Performance Best Practice for Speeding Up Your Web Site.

Google, for example, doesn't waste the extra precious bytes to include a favicon in the source code of its homepage (either using a `<link />` or a Data URI).

Instead, they serve [their favicon](http://www.google.com/favicon.ico) with a HTTP header set far into the future. `Cache-Control: private, max-age=31536000` (31,536,000 seconds = 365 days).

If you're interested in controlling the "freshness" of your site's favicon, you can use Cache-Control and HTTP Headers — for example if you are planning on changing the favicon or don't want it to be cached, you can adjust it accordingly.

An example using [Apache and mod_expires](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/speed-up-sites-with-htaccess-caching.html):

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    # Add Expires Header
    # http://www.askapache.com/?p=152

    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 month"
</IfModule>
```

This module controls the setting of the Expires HTTP header and the max-age directive of the Cache-Control HTTP header in server responses. The expiration date can set to be relative to either the time the source file was last modified, or to the time of the client access.